# is it possible in XSD to define a element that can have different names in XML depending on what kind of data it represents?

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

This was most horrible question title ever, but I hope somebody has time to answer before it's closed.

EDIT: Changed title.
EDIT2: There is approx. 300 component types e.g. tables. And the list changes all the time. If totally dynamic approach is not possible, also string-enumeration could be acceptable because adding new table to this enumerations is easy and should be backward compatible.

A customer wants me to change my current schema in a way that xml:

```
/*0-n components, the outer xml is of no interest in this context */
<component table=ElectricalComponent>
   <id>3</id>
   <class>class1</class>
</component>
<component table=OtherKindOfComponent>
   <id>4</id>
   <class>class2</class>
</component>
```

would look like this:

```
<electricalcomponent>
   <id>3</id>
   <class>class1</class>
</electricalcomponent>
<otherkindofcomponent>
   <id>4</id>
   <class>class2</class>
</otherkindofcomponent>
```

My schema definition is like:

```
<xs:complexType name="tComponent">
   <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="id" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0"/>
      <xs:element name="class" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
   </xs:sequence>
   <xs:attribute name="table" type="xs:string"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="GetComponentResponse">
   <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
       <xs:element name="component" type="tComponent" />
     </xs:sequence>
   </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm interested

- if it's possible without defining a complex type for each of the component types? (I'm not gonna do that, cause it makes no sense.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to have a static schema that constrains the types of the child elements without constraining their names. But does the schema have to be immutable? You could make Component the head of a substitution group, and you could xs:include a module which defines each of the permitted element names as a member of that substitution group, and you could change that included module whenever the list of names changes; if appropriate you could generate the module from a list held in any convenient form.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I try to find out info about substitution groups.

Answer (score 1):

Here you are:

```
<xs:element name="GetComponentResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="electricalcomponent" type="tComponent" />
                <xs:element name="otherkindofcomponent" type="tComponent" />
            </xs:choice>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Above is a valid schema for the input you've mentioned:

```
<electricalcomponent>
   <id>3</id>
   <class>class1</class>
</electricalcomponent>
<otherkindofcomponent>
   <id>4</id>
   <class>class2</class>
</otherkindofcomponent>
```

Comment: Thank you! This might be perfect answer to my question, but set of available component types is ever changing and there is like 300 different component types, so this is not realistic approach in my case.

Comment: XSD schema is a static structure in it's nature. The only other option I see is to go with `xs:any`.

Comment: Thanks Sergey, xs:any is totally out of question because the type of the object could be anything. I would like the type be always be tComponent, but the name of the element anything. I also didn't find a way to do it, so guess it's impossible.